# Язык программирование Си : циклы for

Tags: c, циклы

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
 int fahr;
 for (fahr = 300 ; fahr <= 0 ; fahr = fahr - 20)
    printf ("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5.0/9.0)*(fahr-32));
}
```

почему код не работает ?
Мне надо преобразовать градус фаренгейта в цельсий и напечатать его обратно с 300 до 0

Comment: я знаю что можно исправить с  fahr!= - 20 , но почему тот код не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете неверное условие. Поменяйте `<=` на `>=`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    for(int fahr = 300; fahr >= 0; fahr -= 20)
        printf ("%3d %6.1f\n", fahr, (5/9.)*(fahr-32));
}
```

Comment: @NONAMEISAID https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers